# Should I create different SQL tables for similar usages or create just one with a parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, architecture

In my application (symfony2 / doctrine 2 / mysql), I have a forum and a blog and a small social network.

All require the ability to post some content.

Should I better create different tables for the specific elements (a blog_post, a forum_post, a social_post tables) or create just one post table and attach it to a post_category table which would contain those forum/blog/social_network rows ?

The idea is the usages and specifications for those application parts might become a bit different at a later point in time and though it might be easier to have one single table for the moment, separating them might be easier to maintain in the long run.

What is a best practice in that case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [Table inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) for this.

Having abstract Post entity as parent to BlogPost, ForumPost and SocialPost. This way you'd have standalone entities with DRY properties.